# JavaScript Weird behavior in a condition

Tags: javascript

there's something that i just solved but I don't understand why i got that kind of behavior, here's my js code

```
function fibonacci () {
    let fibonacciNumber = document.getElementById("my-input").value;

    let numberInitialize = 0; 
    let numberNext = 1; 
    let sum = numberInitialize + numberNext;

    if (fibonacciNumber === "" || fibonacciNumber === 0) {
        return (0);
    }


    for (index = 1; index < fibonacciNumber; index++) 
    {
        numberInitialize = numberNext;

        numberNext = sum;

        sum = numberInitialize + numberNext;
        console.log(sum);
        console.log("premier tour");
    }
    console.log(sum);
    document.getElementById("fibo-result").innerHTML = `${sum}`;
}
```

So on the html side I just have an input and im writing down number, my questions concerned this line of code

```
if (fibonacciNumber === "" || fibonacciNumber === 0) {
    return (0);
}
```

when im writing down 0, its still printing one but i write the condition like that

```
if (fibonacciNumber === "" || fibonacciNumber <= 0) {
    return (0);
}
```

its working and when I got 0 as an input nothing is printed like i wanted, my question is: Why when im putting fibonacciNumber === 0 return (0) its not working properly its 0, the condition match no ?

Thanks guys

Comment: Because the actual value from the field is `"0"`, not `0`. And javascript is funny when comparing values...

Comment: Does your input with type number / text ? if it is 'text' you should change it to fibonacciNumber === '0'

Comment: @BarLevin Even if it is type number it will return a string in the `value`

Comment: The strict equality operator (===) checks whether its two operands are equal, returning a Boolean result. Unlike the equality operator, the strict equality operator always considers operands of different types to be different.

Comment: `fibonacciNumber == 0` does it for the purpose

Comment: @charlietfl good to know , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) and then treat the input as integer.

```
let fibonacciNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("my-input").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your field actually has the string `"0"`. The *identity operator* (`===`) will not do any type coercion before comparing the values, so `"0" === 0` is `false`.

Numeric comparison operators like `<=` will do type coercion, so `"0" <= 0` will evaluate to `true`.

You can see this all in action below.

```js
console.log("0" === 0);

console.log("0" <= 0);
```